# How to free up memory of unused parts of a tree in Rust?

Tags: memory, rust, tree

I have the following struct defined:

```
struct Node {
    value: i32,
    children: Vec<Node>,
}
```

I am filling this struct up with random children and values. After this process my root node has 10 direct children and each of them have about 100,000 children. All in all there are a million children. However, now I want to delete the part of the tree that I don't need anymore and free up the memory. I have tried various things. My latest approach is this:

```
let child = &mut root.children.remove(0);
drop(root);
let root = child;
```

However, for some reason this does not free up any memory, when I feel like it should? I am dropping root and that should mean that all the other children (except for [child]) should also be dropped right?
I also looked at Vec's documentation and found this:

> Vec will not specifically overwrite any data that is removed from it, but also won’t specifically preserve it. Its uninitialized memory is scratch space that it may use however it wants. [...] Even if you drop a Vec, its buffer may simply be reused by another allocation.

Despite that, when I add less elements than were removed afterwards, the used memory still increases.

Why is this and how do I fix it?

Comment: If you want to free up the memory you need to call `clear` and `shrink_to_fit`, or `drop(mem::take(&mut node.children))`. Dropping a mutable reference does nothing.

Comment: How do you detect that memory is not freed?

Comment: @prog-fh I look at the amount of memory used with Taskmanager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably just want to replace the value behind the `root` reference since as [Jakub](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13995311/jakub-d%c3%b3ka) noted dropping a mutable reference does not drop whatever it points to:

```rust
struct Node {
    value: i32,
    children: Vec<Node>,
}

impl Drop for Node {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        println!("drop node #{}", self.value);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut root = Node {
        value: 1,
        children: vec![
            Node {
                value: 2,
                children: Vec::new(),
            },
        ],
    };
    let root = &mut root;
    let child = root.children.remove(0);
    *root = child; // {1}
    println!("after reassignment"); // {2}
}
```

prints

```
drop node #1
after reassignment
drop node #2
```

on the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=7c45ed93a73ad7ac9cabf8307f70aee9).
So the root node is dropped at `// {1}`